# how to print looped data from a method

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

i created a method as below: but it only takes the last loop data not all the data to xml for generating pdf,so need a way to generate pdf on a loop from this method

```
def bsku_asin_picking(self):
    website = self.env['website'].search([('company_id', '=', self.env.company.id)], limit=1)
    # print('%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%', website.label_type)
    # vals = []
    for rec in self.move_ids_without_package:
        product = self.env['product.product'].browse(rec.product_id.id)
        data = {
            'quantity': rec.product_uom_qty,
            'display_name': product.display_name,
            'product': product,
        }

        if website.label_type == 'bsku':
            data['barcode_value'] = product.bsku
        else:
            data['barcode_value'] = product.asin
        # vals.append(data)
    return self.env.ref('product_label_bsku_sin.report_product_template_label').report_action(product, data=data)
```

Comment: The `data` variable is reset at each iteration. try to put the values ​​in a list `vals` then loop over it in the report template to print the values. You can call `report_action`  and pass `self` to access the `move_ids_without_package` inside the report template like invoice report.

Comment: Thanks bro for replying, but the method you are saying to pass the data in the form of list and itrate over it. I have already tried that way and that too was unsuccessful.

Comment: How did you pass the list of values and use it in the report template?

Comment: Here data as a dict has quantity, display_name , and barcode_value, but i again added keys to that data as product, and then appended  it to vals which is my list.("please see the commented part") and then i passed my list of dict in data. But i am unable to understand what should i send in the place of product in report action method so in place of product i passed empty list.

Comment: In which model did you declare the `bsku_asin_picking` function?

Comment: Stock.picking model,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables passed through `data` will be available in the rendering context.

***Example:***

```
def bsku_asin_picking(self):

    website = self.env['website'].search([('company_id', '=', self.env.company.id)], limit=1)

    vals = []

    for rec in self.move_ids_without_package:
        product = rec.product_id
        product_data = {
            'quantity': rec.product_uom_qty,
            'display_name': product.display_name,
            'product': product,
        }
        if website.label_type == 'bsku':
            product_data['barcode_value'] = product.bsku
        else:
            product_data['barcode_value'] = product.asin
        vals.append(product_data)

    datas = {'vals': vals}

    return self.env.ref('product_label_bsku_sin.action_report_product_template_label').report_action(self, data=datas)
```

Then you can loop over `vals` and print product data.

***Example:***

```
<t t-foreach="vals" t-as="product_data">
    <p t-out="product_data['quantity']"/>
    <p t-out="product_data['display_name']"/>
    <p t-out="product_data['product']"/>
    <p t-out="product_data['barcode_value']"/>
</t>
```

### Alternative

You can also call `report_action` without `data` and loop over the `move_ids_without_package`:

***Example:***

```
<t t-set="website_label_type" t-value="doc.env['website'].search([('company_id', '=', doc.env.company.id)], limit=1)"/>

<t t-foreach="doc.move_ids_without_package" t-as="line">
    <p t-out="line.product_uom_qty"/>
    <p t-out="line.display_name"/>
    <p t-out="line.product_id.name"/>
    
    <t t-if="website_label_type == 'bsku'">
        <span t-out="line.product_id.bsku"/>
    </t>
    <t t-else="">
        <span t-out="line.product_id.asin"/>
    </t>
</t>
```